# How to represent a buffer as linked list in C

Tags: c, linux, data-structures, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I have preallocated buffer (array of chars) to which strings are being written, it looks like this:
"This\0buffer\0contains\0strings\00000..."

I want to be able to remove the last string, so I came up with the idea to represent each string in the buffer as a linked list node with pointers to its start and end, so I would just find the last node and fill the region it holds with zeros.

```
struct node 
{ 
  char *str_start;
  char *str_end;
  struct node *next; 
};
```

It looks like a very common problem, however, I failed to find such implementations anywhere.

The question is: Is there some data structure for my usecase I overlooked, or is there a better solution to do this?

Note: This is to be used in the kernel module, so maybe it's already implemented in kernel

Comment: Is there anything wrong with your solution? Looks fine to me.

Comment: Do you mean that you have an input like the buffer described and a strategy for implementation but can't work parsing the buffer data into nodes?

Comment: I just wondering if there is a data structure to partition a buffer into a linked list nodes, so I would not implement it myself and just reuse what already exists

Comment: You could start reading the buffer backwards. When you find a char different from '\0' you found the last letter of the last string. Keep going until you find another '\0'. Then use `memset` to set the buffer to '\0' from the char following last '\0' you found to the end of the buffer.

Comment: If you want to remove the last string multiple times you could save in another structure the indexes from where string in the buffer begin and end and remove them with `memset`

Comment: Since your strings are zero terminated, you don't need two pointers in your node. A node could simply be a pointer to the data (in this case, a string), and a pointer to the next node. This is a very generic and common linked list node structure and you should be able to find numerous examples.

Comment: why keep a pointer to the start and end of the string instead of just the start and keep a variable with the size of the string?

Comment: @lurker
Thank you! Indeed it's much better to have only a pointer to start.

Comment: Instead of solving the issue (where none exists by the way), you are introducing an overengineered "solution". There is **no** problem at all. There is no additional overcomplicated structure is needed.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a 2 dimensional array (considering the buffer is preallocated and you know of a maximum size for every string).

That would make enforcing string sizes easier, hence your code more secure.